# Trying to integrate unit tests into Xcode for iOS 5.0 project, but cannot get files to link correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to add unit tests into my Xcode project for an iOS app that I am working on. I have SenTest working with basic examples, but the second I try to test any of the project code, I get linker errors like so:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Account", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Obviously, I could solve this by duplicating my app target configuration into my test configuration, making all of the compile sources the same and such, but this will make two different targets that I will have to maintain, which is very unappealing. Also, I could refactor the project to use a static library and share between the app and the test targets, but that also is undesirable.

Is there any way that I can use the built objects from the app target in the test target? This sure seems like a lot of work to get unit testing in my project...

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: When I get link errors unit testing with Xcode 4, I can make them go away by making the implementation files in my app target members of the unit testing target. Open the file inspector to see the Target Membership section.

Comment: Yeah but then you have to maintain two different Target Membership sections, and who wants to do that? I have over 100 .m files and I need 90% of them in the Target Section to compile and run tests.